# Javascript update and access variable outside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, function, variables

I must be doing something wrong. I was hoping the code below would update and access the global variable 'gvar' but it doesn't. What I'm I doing wrong please?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var gvar;
    $(function () {                     
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON("json.php", function (myData) {
                $.each(myData.tag, function (t, myData) {
                    if(myData.myId != null) {
                        gvar = myData.myId;
                    }
                });
                return false;
            })
        });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(gvar);
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried alert(gvar); outside the function ?

Comment: Is that a typo in your example code?  You do alert(myId), not alert(gvar).  Other than that it should work.

Comment: Yes, sorry, typo... should be alert(gvar)... still doesn't return anything though

Comment: You're alerting `gvar` while it is probably not *filled* as `$.getJSON` is asynchron.

Answer (score 3):

`gvar` is only being populated as soon as the dom is ready. The alert, however, is executed as soon as that part of the code is parsed. Try putting the alert at the end of the `ready()` function.

@Yoshi has another good point I just missed: Population of the variable is even delayed until the request has been executed successfully. To test it, you could set a timeout of some seconds and then alert the variable. The request should have been over by then and the variable will have a value that can be alerted. But this is just for the purpose of testing whether the variable works in the global scope or not, because when alerting inside the callback, of course the variable has been set right above the alert. ;)

Comment: I've got a fix but apparently, I can't post the code as an answer until after 6hrs. Anyway, Many thanks guys!